# How to pass an inline js action into an external js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have fairly limited knowledge of JS, but we have an action on the page which leads to an if statement in the external js file. I am using (event.toElement) which works in chrome but not ie, ff or opera.

inline js

```
    $("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-card").dialog2IFrame(  { 
            height:900,
              closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
              closeOnEscape: true, 
              removeOnClose: true, 
              showCloseHandle: true,
}); 

    $("div#jquery-live-search .dialog-iframe-report").dialog2IFrame(    { 
                height:900,
                  closeOnOverlayClick: true, 
                  closeOnEscape: true, 
                  removeOnClose: true, 
                  showCloseHandle: true,
    }); 
    });
```

external js

```
var parentHtml = "";
            if ($(event.toElement).hasClass("dialog-iframe-card")) {
            parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_CARD);
            } else if ($(event.toElement).hasClass("dialog-iframe-report")) {
            parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_REPORT);
            }
```

parentHTML has a variable at the start of the js file, which is loaded when the if statement makes the switch. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the correct action to the external file whilst working in a browser other than chrome.

I also tried the following which only worked on chrome...

```
var $target = $(event.target);
                if ($target.hasClass("dialog-iframe-card")) {
                parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_CARD);
                } else if ($target.hasClass("dialog-iframe-report")) {
                parentHtml = $(__DIALOG_HTML_REPORT);
                }
```

The suggested answer does NOT answer or solve the question.

Comment: Looked at that, couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event.target to figure out the element that triggered the event. Look at this http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: Thanks, still lost on this one